# Bootstrap 3 overlapping content issue. Sidebar collapse with button

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, sidebar, overlapping

I have come up with a bootstrap 3 layout I like, but it has a bug.  I created an example page on Bootply.com that describes the problem.  Basically the page works except for when you expand and collapse the sidebar, then resize the browser page to full width again.  The footer and the sidebar content overlap. You can see the example page here:  http://www.bootply.com/CxdX89ofTg

Thanks for any help you can come up with!

Comment: why you will expand collapse then go full size .... if you are in mobile view thats mean you open from mobile SO there is no go full screen there is no use of the site were the problem will happen .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Javascript is adding style="height:0px;" to the element after hiding the nav-menu. You have to set the height to 'auto' on resizing above the breakpoint.

I forked your example: http://www.bootply.com/28P8HqzYUA#

See line 9 in the JS.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks so much!  I think this is a good basic template for an ecommerce site with a lot of shopping categories.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem! If this solved your problem, please consider marking it as right solution or upvote it. Thanks!

Comment: I clicked the upvote arrow, but I'm too new for it to matter yet.  Thanks though.